# Difference between delete[i] array and delete array[i]

Tags: c++, arrays

I actually want to describe my problem first. In my code I've a base class with name Employee then I've 4 more classes. I wanted to make my class abstract (basically i was using polymorphism concept). I made a pointer array with type of base class and add objects in it(unnamed objects on heap). Now i wanted to deallocate objects. I used `delete[i] array` and `delete array[i]` both were working(one at a time). Can someone please explain the difference between both of them? Why both were working if `delete[i]` is wrong?
I was using `delete[i] array` or `delete array[i]` with for loop.

`main` is like:

```
Employee *arr[10];
arr[0] =new SalariedEmployee ("first name","last name","number",200);
```

now i want to delete this object

Comment: `delete[i] array` seems invalid, you probably mean `delete[] array;`

Comment: *"I actually want to describe my problem first"* But code is more accurate.

Comment: Both are wrong. Use standard containers and smart pointers

Comment: No, i was not using dynamic array. My array was of fixed size 10. I was talking about deallocating objects :)

Comment: I had a brainfart, my answer is incorrect.

Comment: What should i do :0

Comment: Kindly someone explain this :0

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some actual code that shows what you describe.

Comment: Code is so big in size I've like 5 header files and 5 cpp files

Comment: Employee *arr[10];

Comment: We don't need the whole code, we just need a  [mre].

Comment: Arr[0] =new SalariedEmployee ("firstname","lastname","number",200);

Comment: please have a look I've edited my question

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you. [`delete[i] array` is a syntax error](https://godbolt.org/z/YzbHRW)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it was not giving me any error

Comment: Then you need to put actual code that reproduces what you're saying in the question. Also include the compiler name and and version you're using.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete[i] array;
```

is wrong in standard C++. *But* it acutally compiles on msvc [(demo)](https://godbolt.org/z/P9kcBP). It's a compiler specific extension (thanks to Blastfurnace for pointing this out).

The correct version is

```
delete array[i];
```

to destroy an object that was allocated on the heap and free the corresponding memory.

However, manual memory management can become quite hard sometimes. So the solution in modern C++ would be something like

```
std::array<std::uniqe_ptr<Employee>, 10> array;
```

for a fixed size array with pointers to `Employee`'s.

Comment: If you add the `/W4` compiler option it shows "warning C4208: nonstandard extension used: delete [exp] - exp evaluated but ignored". It's a non-conforming extension.

Comment: If you disable language extensions with `/Za` it shows "error C2203: delete operator cannot specify bounds for an array".

Comment: @Blastfurnace `/Za` is soft-deprecated for C++ because it has numerous bugs. Don’t use it, use `/permissive-` instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, that's good to know (I see the note on the MSDN page about it). Unfortunately `/permissive-` doesn't emit an error for this :(

Comment: @Blastfurnace Well that sucks.